Multiple files Vyper contract verification
I deployed a contract initializing snekmate.auth.ownable, but cannot find a way to verify it on etherscan.
I tried multi-part verification on blockscout with different naming of library, but compiler could not fetch it.

Found out etherscan does not support multiple files for Vyper yet, though blockscout worked this way:
1.
vyper -f solc_json Contract.vy > Contract.json


Verify using Vyper (Standard JSON input)

